Apollo Client cannot create multiple items at once using directus
Alright I have a event_datetime data model in directus, I am trying too create multiple of these at once, using the apollo client in react native. This is my mutation:
mutation CreateEventDatetimes ($data: [create_event_datetimes_input!]!) {
  create_event_datetimes_items(data: $data) {
    id
    rrule
  }
}

Now any array of data i give it, it always gives me the same error:
[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$data" got invalid value [function sort] at "data.sort"; Int cannot represent non-integer value: [function sort], Path: undefined

I give it an array of dummy data and it fails, I give it an array of actual data and it also fails. I dont know what to do. I've looked and there is a sort field in the event datetime data model, But i dont know why its causing an error, because it should not check for any sort field in the array but the data inside it!
Here is the code for calling the function and some dummy data:
      const datesToCreate = [
      {
        timezone: "Test/Shit",
      },
      {
        timezone: "Test/Shit2",
      }
    ];

    await useCreateDateMutation({
      variables: {
        data: datesToCreate,
      },
      onCompleted: (data) => {
        dateIds.push(...data);
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
    });

Please help, I've spend three days on this.
